# Rotate a curve to match a model curve

Tags: geometry, curves, angle

I have a given curve which could be in any direction and I have a model curve which is fixed,I have find the angle by which I have to rotate the moving curve so that it matches the fixed curve
  I have tried to find the angle between the normal to the planes on which the curve lies but it doesn't work. Any other  ideas that I could do to find the angle.

-swetha

Comment: Are these curves on the same plane? How are they expressed? In fact, why not just give us the equations of the curves, or some representative case?

Comment: These curves are not on same plane.i have set of 3d points which lie on the curve. I have found the plane equation by taking a cross product of points